# LINQ - Operator to be used to return all records

Tags: linq

What operator needs to be used when I want all the records to be returned irrespective I have one or multiple record.

Below is the example:

```
        public static async Task<SampleDataItem> GetFavouriteItemAsync(string uniqueId)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "11","12"};



        await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
       var matches = _sampleDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where(item=>lst.Contains(item.UniqueId));



        if (matches.Count() !=0) return (SampleDataItem)matches.AsEnumerable();
        return null;

    }
```

matches.First() return only first record; however I want all the records present in matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static async Task<List<SampleDataItem>> GetFavouriteItemAsync(string uniqueId)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "11","12"};

    await _sampleDataSource.GetSampleDataAsync();
    // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
    var matches = _sampleDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where(item=>lst.Contains(item.UniqueId));


    if (matches.Any()) 
    {
      var ReturnTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => matches .ToList());  
      return await ReturnTask;  
    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: I am getting following error with above code
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HubApp1.Data.SampleDataItem>' to 'HubApp1.Data.SampleDataItem'

Comment: @VarunKhanna see my updates: Task<List<SampleDataItem>>